# c# Socket Stream using Tcp protocol

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp

I'am Using Socket Stream , protocol Tcp for Connection between server and Clients 
with Extern IP Adress .
My Problem is I don't Receive the full Data that was sent by the client ! 
I v tried to shearch many solution , and i got to know that i have to send the `Data Size` First then send The `Actual Data` , it was just what i did for example :

```
string Data = ""; // my data here 
string Crypted = crypt(Data); // just a method crypting string (work perfectly tested)
byte[] DataBytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(Crypted);
_ClientSocket.Send(BitConverter.GetBytes(DataBytes.Length),0,4,0);
_ClientSocket.Send(DataBytes,0,DataBytes.Length,0);
```

And for Receive Somethign Like that  :

```
 byte[] uffer;
            byte[] BufferData;
            int Size;
            int Received;
            uffer = new byte[4];
            while (true)
            {
                uffer = new byte[4];
                Size = _Client.Receive(uffer, 0, 4, 0);
                if (Size > 0)
                {
                    if (Size < _Client.ReceiveBufferSize)
                    {
                        BufferData = new byte[Size];
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        BufferData = new byte[_Client.ReceiveBufferSize];

                    }
                    Received = _Client.Receive(BufferData, 0, BufferData.Length, 0);
                    string Msg = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(buffer);
                    String Data = U.Decrypt(Msg);

                }
```

But i still Don't Receive Data, and if i did i don't receive it full !

Comment: Please edit the question to use code that actually shows the issue (ie. is a complete and minimal re-create). Note 1 I've used this approach in the past and it has worked; 2. please use normal .NET naming conventions and the [SO] syntax highlighting will work better (it is pretty simplistic).

Comment: The 4 size bytes to in `uffer`, the message goes in `BufferData`, but you decode `buffer`, which isn't used anywhere else in the code snippet.

Comment: @Richard thats my code its the issued code .

Comment: @Evenhuls the first buffer uffer Receive the Buffer Size ,, and the buffer receive the actually data

Answer (score 1):

I think you're mixing up the result of the first receive with the value received.

After:

> ```
> Size = _Client.Receive(uffer, 0, 4, 0);
> ```

`Size` will be the number of bytes received by that API call, but just after you're using it to size the buffer for the main content.

You need to convert the content of `uffer` into an `int` and use that to size the buffer for the next receive. Ie. your missing a:

```
int messageSize = BitConverter.ToInt32(uffer, 0);
BufferData = new byte [Math.Min(messageSize, _Client.ReceiveBufferSize];
```

Comment: Thank You for your Answer ! , , but i still don't get all the result i have a foreachloop that send Data for example Foreach Process in Processes will be sent to the Server i only Receive like 4 or 5 Processes

Comment: @CruDy Add plenty of logging to both your client and server, and work through. The smallest thing not being quite what you expect could be the clue you need. At [SO] we can only go on the information you put in the question.